# How many SSH key's should I have? Should I reuse them?

Tags: ssh-keys

I'm a graphic designer working with developers and so I need to access many servers and accounts at GitHub and BitBucket via SSH.

I'm a bit confused, how many SSH keys should I have? What is the best practice?

It appears that I have several:

- Some are linked to the actual computer I'm using such as my desktop or laptop
- Some are linked to a specific email account (private email, work email, etc)

Should I be reusing the same SSH keys on multiple servers?

Along those same lines, are there any best practices for naming conventions, other than id_rsa?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the InfoSecurity stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you have one private (id_rsa) and one public (id_rsa.pub) key per device.

You can use the same public key for different services (GitHub, BitBucket, ssh, ..)